# adding photo to the pop up field in qgis2web?

Tags: qgis, popup, image, qgis2web, web

I want to add charts on my web map in a way that when i click on the point the chart appears in the pop up field.    [image]

Do i have to add it as an image in the attribute? 
Can i do that when the pictures are in my hard drive and not in a html form?